# Merge / Join two data frames based on 3 columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df_pp and df_epc containing 3 common columns, POSTCODE, HOUSE_NAME, HOUSE_NUMBER. I want to merge these two dataframes into one dataset using the following logic.

**(POSTCODE && (HOUSE_NAME  || HOUSE_NUMBER))**

So, I want to pick a row in the new merged dataset if the postcode matches and either of the house number or house names match. I tried the following code. But it is not what I expected.

`new_df = pd.merge(left=df_epc, right=df_pp, on=['POSTCODE', 'HOUSE_NUMBER', 'HOUSE_NAME'], how='inner') #690`

Comment: See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your logic correctly you want to do a outer join on HOUSE_NAME and HOUSE_NUMBER (union).

Then you want to do a inner join on POSTCODE (intersection).

You need to understand the difference between how you join and give some more information about what  you except in the end.

Comment: But none of these 3 columns has unique values for each row. 1 value of POSTCODE can appear several times in other house numbers, house name. Similarly, the house name "Maple" can appear several times when the postcode and house number is different.

Comment: Do you want the unique combinations? Maybe you can provide a sample and what  you expect after the merge?

Answer (score 0):

You can inner merge on only the column `POSTCODE` and then filter by [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) on either `HOUSE_NUMBER` or `HOUSE_NAME` matches on the  sources dataframe columns, as follows:

```
new_df = pd.merge(left=df_epc, right=df_pp, on='POSTCODE', how='inner') 

new_df_out = new_df.query('(HOUSE_NAME_x == HOUSE_NAME_y) | (HOUSE_NUMBER_x == HOUSE_NUMBER_y)')
```

The inner merge on column `POSTCODE` ensures the `POSTCODE` matches on the 2 source dataframes.  The filtering by [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) then additionally ensures either one of the `HOUSE_NUMBER` or `HOUSE_NAME` matches.

**Demo**

```
print(df_epc)

   POSTCODE HOUSE_NAME  HOUSE_NUMBER
0  ABC-1234      Name1           567
1  DEF-5678        NaN           678
2  XYZ-2345      Name3           123

print(df_pp)

   POSTCODE HOUSE_NAME  HOUSE_NUMBER
0  ABC-1234      Name1           NaN
1  DEF-5678      Name2         678.0
2  XYZ-2345      Name4         456.0

new_df = pd.merge(left=df_epc, right=df_pp, on='POSTCODE', how='inner') 

print(new_df)

   POSTCODE HOUSE_NAME_x  HOUSE_NUMBER_x HOUSE_NAME_y  HOUSE_NUMBER_y
0  ABC-1234        Name1             567        Name1             NaN
1  DEF-5678          NaN             678        Name2           678.0
2  XYZ-2345        Name3             123        Name4           456.0

new_df_out = new_df.query('(HOUSE_NAME_x == HOUSE_NAME_y) | (HOUSE_NUMBER_x == HOUSE_NUMBER_y)')

print(new_df_out)

   POSTCODE HOUSE_NAME_x  HOUSE_NUMBER_x HOUSE_NAME_y  HOUSE_NUMBER_y
0  ABC-1234        Name1             567        Name1             NaN
1  DEF-5678          NaN             678        Name2           678.0
```